# Migrating from C# to Java, int & ushort (Bitwise AND)

Tags: java, c#, bit-manipulation

I've been given a section of code written in C# that I have to migrate to Java. In C#, the code boils down to:

```
int foo = getFooValue();
UInt16 bar = 0x0080;
if((foo & bar) == 0)
{
  doSomeCoolStuff()
}
```

Given that java doesn't have unsigned number types, how do I do this in Java?

Comment: You can just use `int` in this particular case (even though it's signed).

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou is right. The idea of unsigned int is that it allows you to fit positive values to double the normal int value (namely `65535` for `uint16`). However, in this case your value is `128` which definitely fits normal `int16`

Comment: And since the constant bar is defined in hex and used only for logical operation, it does not matter even if the value falls under negative zone.

Comment: @ZakiAnwarHamdani It actually does, because it is being compared to an `int`. The signed negative short will expand with two bytes of ones on the left, while the unsigned will expand with zeros.

Comment: Why even use any "narrow" type? You can use an `int` in both C# and Java.

Comment: Oh yeah.. But compiler wont allow out of range values (short bar = 0xFF80;) gives compilation error.

Comment: The JVM itself doesn't have unsigned arithmetic. In the rare cases where you really need to do unsigned arithmetic, the wrapper class `Integer` (and `Long`) has methods for any unsigned arithmetic operation you might want. In practice, hardly anyone ever finds a need to use them.

Comment: My concern was whether doing the bitwise AND comparison would change if I went from `int & ushort` to `int & int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to worry about the `unsigned` type since `0x0080` (decimal `128`) absolutely fills a `short`, whose maximum value is `32767`.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    short flag = 0x0080;

    int foo1 = 128; // 0x00000080

    if ((foo1 & flag) == 0)
        System.out.println("Hit 1!");

    int foo2 = 0; // 0x00000000

    if ((foo2 & flag) == 0)
        System.out.println("Hit 2!");

    int foo3 = 27698; // 0x00006C32

    if ((foo3 & flag) == 0)
        System.out.println("Hit 3!");
}

// Output: Hit 2! Hit 3!
```